# Is there is a step by step tutorial to work Stripe Connect?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I need to implement **Stripe Connect** for my company. Previously, I was following a **Stripe** guide by [CodeCourse on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWHn4uErhCQEk1EIUjSGkuDk). I'm a new developer, so step by step instruments really help. The documentation for **Stripe Connect** is slightly confusing and I need some help.

If there is not a step by step guide you know about, would you mind writing down the major steps and the respective links for each step?

I know this is a lot to ask, but I'm stuck and could really use some help.

Comment: Stripe has the Rocket Rides demo, similar to cab-hailing apps with a server in NodeJS and an iOS application, that uses Connect Express: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-connect-rocketrides/ . Stripe also has a Kavholm, a demo for Connect Custom and similar to holiday booking, at https://github.com/stripe/stripe-demo-connect-kavholm-marketplace . Connect Standard is the easiest of all and I don't think it has a demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So Stripe actually has "recipes" for making Connect based on a few different business types.  They're available at the following page:

https://stripe.com/docs/recipes#connect

If you're a Rails Developer, there's also a pre-built example available on GitHub here, that I personally found very helpful:

https://github.com/rfunduk/rails-stripe-connect-example

I hope that helps.

Cheers + Good luck!